# Find the limit $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\cos \left(\pi\sqrt{n^{2}-n} \right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, radicals

I'd love your help with finding the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\cos (\pi\sqrt{n^{2}-n}).$$

I was asked to find this limit, but honestly I believe that it doesn't exist.

According to Heine Theorem of limit of functions, I can choose two sequences:

$x_{k}=2\pi k$ and $y_{k}=2\pi k+\pi$ and notice that when I apply the function on both of them, I'll get -1 and 1, respectively.

Am I right?

Thank you again.

Comment: Do you mean to have that $\pi$ in your sequences?  There's already multiplication by $\pi$ inside the cosine.  Or did you plan to start with, say, $x_k$, and work backwards to a sequence of $n_k$ such that $\cos\pi\sqrt{n_k^2-n_k} = \cos{x_k}$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. without the $\pi$'s. thanks.

Comment: You kinda started the wrong way, by asking what **tool** to use.  Your first question should have been "what's happening here?" It is then natural to calculate, for largish but not too large $n$. (Not too large because if you take $n=10^9$, roundoff error kills you.) So look at $n=100, 101, 102$. Calculate. You will get answers near $0$.  And while you are taking $\sqrt{n^2-n}$, you may notice it is almost exactly halfway between consecutive integers.  Now an idea for a proof may come.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
\cos (\pi\sqrt{n^2-n})&= (-1)^n\cos(\pi(\sqrt{n^2-n}-n))\\
&= (-1)^n \cos\pi\frac{-n}{\sqrt{n^2-n}+n}\\
&=(-1)^n\cos \pi\frac 1{\sqrt{1-\frac 1n }+1},
\end{align*}
hence $|\cos(\pi\sqrt{n^2-n})| = \left|\cos \left(\pi\frac 1{\sqrt{1-\frac 1n }+1}\right)\right|$. 
Since $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\pi\frac 1{\sqrt{1-\frac 1n }+1} =\frac{\pi}2$, the $\cos$ is continuous and $\cos \frac{\pi}2 =0$ we conclude that the limit is $0$.

Comment: It is intresting that when you go by intuition and write the limit as $\cos \pi n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}$ you sincerely might think that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Nir Yes, I agree. The idea comes from an exercise that I've done some years ago. I had to look at the convergence of the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})$.

Comment: Are you sure of this answer?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+cos%28pi*sqrt+%28n^2-n%29%29

Comment: @Nir: it is very important that $n$ here is integer.

Answer (score 64):

Since a nice formal argument has been supplied by Davide Giraudo, I will allow myself the luxury of informality.

Let $n$ be a large positive integer.
Complete the square. We have 
$$n^2-n=\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{1}{4}$$

Take the square root.  When $n$ is very large, the term $-1/4$ makes a vanishingly small contribution to the square root.

So our square root is nearly equal to $n-1/2$. And the cosine of $\pi n -\pi/2$ is $0$.

Answer (score 6):

Considering the form $\cos(\pi n \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}})$ and using
Taylor's expansion for $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}$ $\to$ [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20sqrt%281-1/x%29),
we get that when n is large $\cos (\pi\sqrt{n^{2}-n}) \approx \cos( \pi n -\frac{\pi}{2})$. Therefore, $L=0$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Nice answer Chris's sis........