# How to find the limit of $\cos^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2-n})$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have been ask to find the limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}
\cos^2(\pi\sqrt{n^2-n})$

However surely as $n$ gets larger the expression inside the $\cos$ function tends to infinity and the whole thing oscillates between $0$ and $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the fact that for all integers $n$ we have $\cos^2(x)=\cos^2(x-\pi n)$.

Comment: Fairly sure that this is essentially a duplicate. Gimme a minute.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46065/lim-n-to-infty-cos-pi-sqrtn2-n-second-battle

Comment: Good job @AnthonyPeter. The key idea is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

A start: First show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-\sqrt{n^2-n})=\frac{1}{2}$.  So for large $n$, the cosine of $\pi\sqrt{n^2-n}$ is close to the cosine of $\pi n-\frac{\pi}{2}$.