# Does $\sum_{n\ge0} \sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2+n+1}) $ converge/diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

How would you prove convergence/divergence of the following series?

$$\sum_{n\ge0} \sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2+n+1}) $$

I'm interested in more ways of proving convergence/divergence for this series.

**My thoughts**

Let
$$u_{n}= \sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2+n+1})$$
trying to bound $$|u_n|\leq |\sin(\pi(n+1) )| $$ since $n^2+n+1\leq n^2+2n+1$ and $\sin$ is decreasing in $(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} )$

$$\sum_{n\ge0}|u_n|\leq \sum_{n\ge0}|\sin(\pi(n+1) )|$$
or $|\sin(\pi(n+1) )|=0\quad  \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\sum_{n\ge0}|\sin(\pi(n+1) )|=0$
thus $\sum_{n\ge0} u_n$ is converge absolutely then is converget

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think your bound is not correct because sinus is not a non-decreasing function.

Comment: is decreasing in $(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} )$

Comment: But $\pi\sqrt{n^2+n+1}$ does not belong to $(0,\pi/2)$. More to the point, a prerequisite for the series to converge would be to have $u_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. Is it the case?

Comment: @ClementC. i don't think so, it is diverge

Comment: Then, if $u_n$ does not converge to 0, the series $\sum u_n$ cannot converge.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349522/calculate-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sin-pi-sqrtn2n1) is about limit of the n-th term of your series.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** 
A necessary condition for the convergence of an infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is that the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ should exist and be equal $0$.
So for your series investigate the following limit :

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right).
$$

Comment: Why? Isn't $\sqrt{n^2+n+1} \approx \sqrt{n^2+2n+1} = (n+1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ? So $\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n+1}) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Why did you downvote?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg((n+1) - \sqrt{n^2+n+1}\bigg) = ?$$

Comment: @VolodymyrFomenko, you are wrong! This limit does not exist. See this in http://www.wolframalpha.com/.

Comment: @VolodymyrFomenko $\sin$ is a periodic function.

Comment: @JohnJoy, good example. :)

Comment: @user201168 i know that and i upvote only the detailed answers and i ask for different ways to prove that not just the hint

Comment: @Educ Then you'll probably upvote not that many answers. Many members in this site think that hints and not completely detailed answers is what serves askers the best. In fact, completely detailed answers are more usually given by newcomers or greenhorns than by veterans.

Comment: here is conterexample of what you said : user201168 is member for 19 days then he is newcomer and he just give the hint not detailed answer so what you say is generally not true

Comment: @Alex Silva I have a bit of egg on my face. Initially I assumed that the limit that I proposed earlier converged to zero, but upon further investigation I realize that that was very incorrect. In fact,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg((n+1)-\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\bigg) = \frac{1}{2}$$
Kudos to you for your insight.

Comment: @Educ, you can distinguish between "more usually" and "always", right?

Comment: @Timbuc, you can distinguish between "generally true" and "Always True ", right?

Comment: @Educ Perhaps I can, perhaps I cannot, yet what *I wrote*, and this is what you addressed, is "usually" . :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n+1}) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\Bigg(\pi \  \sqrt{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4} + 1}\Bigg) \\&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\Bigg(\pi \  \sqrt{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4}\Big)}\Bigg) \\&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\Bigg(\pi \  \Big(n+\frac{1}{2}\Big)\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{4(n+\frac{1}{2})^2}}\Bigg)\end{align}$$

then this limit changes between $1$ and $-1$.

Thus you may conclude that the series diverges.

Comment: I think this is very nice and correct, since expression inside the squared root is almost 1 for big n's and what is left is $\;\sin\pi(n+0.5)\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sin\left(\pi\cdot\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right)}=\sin{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\pi\cdot\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right)}=$$

$$=\sin\left(\pi\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-(n+1)+(n+1)\right)\right)=$$

$$=\sin\left(\pi\cdot\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-(n+1)\right)+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(n+1\right)\right)\right)=$$

$$=\sin\left(\pi\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(-\frac12+(n+1)\right)\right)=$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{n}$$

Comment: There are several major mistakes in the above, imo: first, to use arithmetic of limits one *must* have that each of the expression part's limit exists finitely. This is not the case with $\;\lim (n+1)\;$ . Second, the one before last line has the expression $\;n+1\;$ there, so what happened with the limit?? Third, in order to exchange limit and function as done in the first line, one must either have the function is continuous where $\;n\;$ tends or prove otherwise the change is possible. None is done/fulfilled here.

Comment: You also need to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-(n+1)\bigg) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: The very tiny correction made to this answer doesn't address the above questions.